# Count character in word jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i count character in word with jQuery?

```
function count(word, character)
{
   return ???;
}
```

for example:

```
count('atesta', 'a'); // should return 2
count('testaaa', 'a'); // should return 3
```

etc

Comment: You can't. jQuery does not provide any string methods. You have to use plain JavaScript for that.

Comment: `word.match(/a/g).length`

Comment: @elclanrs That's not extremely helpful because `'a'` is contained in a variable so you have to show the way to do it with a dynamically-constructed regex.

Comment: @ErikE: Yeah, I wouldn't even make a function for this, I would just do it inline, reads well. That's why I posted as comment though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why must everything be in jQuery?

```
function count(haystack, needle) {
    return haystack.split(needle).length-1;
}
```